# gdb function call to a std::vector from the local scope results in error

Tags: c++, debugging, function, stl, scope

I am testing a function `vect_dbg(vector<int>)` that returns the contents of a STL vector as a C string, so I can call it with gdb `output vect_dbg(test)` or put it in a watch.

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> test; //breakpoint; output vect_dbg(test) ends debugging.
    for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) test.push_back(i);
    return 0;
}

#include<sstream>
const char* vect_dbg(const vector<int> &V)
{
    stringstream ss;
    for (int i=0;i<V.size();i++)
        ss<<"V["<<i<<"]:"<<V[i]<<' ;'; //line 16
    static char sEnu[256];
    ss.getline(sEnu,256);
    return sEnu;
}
```

Unfortunately, `output vect_dbg(test)` breaks the debugging.

> The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called
>   from GDB. GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
>   To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off" Evaluation of the
>   expression containing the function (vect_dbg(std::vector > const&)) will be abandoned. Program received
>   signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x004014b1 in vect_dbg
>   (V=@0x22ff34) at main.cpp:16

I discovered that the function works if I make `test` global, but i couldn't figure out a solution for the locally defined vector. How can i solve this? Many thanks.

EDIT: Mainly solved, the answer was pretty obvious, the vector wasn't initialized at breakpoint. Now i am wondering if it's possible to detect that in `vect_dbg`. 
An alternative i found is to declare the `vector<int>` static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put breakpoint one line after (on `for` loop). The variable `test` was not yet initialized when you trying to use it.

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out what you're saying. The constructor for `test` hasn't been run yet when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: you are right, thank you. it's weird cause I remember it was the first thing i tried.